# Manipulate data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to modify my data frame in R. My current data frame is:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3), A = c(10, 20, 30), B = c(0, 0, 1)) 

df_transposed <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>% pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = Value)
```

I need modify my data frame to the follow form:

```
row   A  X1_cen   B   X2_cen ....
X1    10   0      11  1    
X2    12   0      13  0
```

I need the code in R to modify my dataframe. The packages and more :)

Comment: Please include your example data as code we can load. That makes it easier for people to help you, and by reducing ambiguity makes it more likely you'll see solutions that actually work for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You're looking for a combination of subsetting and a transpose.  See this article: https://www.statology.org/dplyr-transpose/

Comment: This is my current problem, the code is:

Example data frame
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3), A = c(10, 20, 30), B = c(0, 0, 1))

Transpose the data frame
df_transposed <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>% pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = Value)

But I need the information of B in columns in the right of 1, 2, and 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is what (it sounds like) you want:

```
df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -ID, names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>% 
    mutate(ID = paste0(Variable, "_", ID) ) %>%
    select(-Variable) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = Value)

# A tibble: 1 × 6
    A_1   B_1   A_2   B_2   A_3   B_3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    10     0    20     0    30     1
```

Keep in mind that putting two variables into your column names is extremely poor data practices, so if you're using this for any real world application I would caution against it